# Do not load the session with reactjs/axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, session, express, axios

I have my application with react and nodejs / express

I am creating my session and it works for me when I test in postman, but when I load it with axios in react it does not show me the session, it always returns me empty the array, this is my code

Express

```
app.use(session({ secret: '23eirofjiw8'resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));

app.get('/token', function(req, res, next){
       userServices.verificaToken(req.query, function(err, token){
                if(!token){
                    return res.json({ status: 'FAIL', message: 'Usuario Innactivo'}) 

                } else{
                    userServices.activaUsuario(req.query.email, function(err, Activado){
                        if (Activado) {
                            return res.json({ status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'User activate', user: req.query.email });                
                        }
                    })
                   req.session.user=req.query.email 
                }
            }) 
    })
```

and with react / axios

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/sign_up_profile", data)
    .then((response) =>{
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express session stores session ID in cookies but axios response doesn't contain cookies data so you cannot see the session ID that has been set. In order to access cookies you can use `document.cookie` object.

Example :

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/sign_up_profile", data)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("Cookies are ", document.cookie)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Something went wrong!", err)
    });
```

Comment: document.cookie will return empty string if httpOnly is set which is set by default